# Update & security patch both

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, patches

I would like to know you kindly ... I have installed update 1.9.3.3 .. should I also install the SUPEE -9767 patch? Or is the latter included in the previous update? Thanks a lot CM

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not need to install path SUPEE -9767, in official documentation of this path https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-9767 you can see:

Patches and upgrades are available for the following Magento versions:

- Community Edition 1.5.0.1-1.9.3.2: SUPEE-9767 **or** upgrade to Community Edition 1.9.3.3
- Enterprise Edition 1.9.0.0-1.14.3.2: SUPEE-9767 **or** upgrade to Enterprise Edition 1.14.3.3